# R: How to perform a (user defined) calculation based on column criteria and percentage values of another df?

Tags: r, aggregate, subset, apply

I want to calculate the percentage values for a `data.frame` column based on criterion of another object's column using percentages of another df. Here is some example data:

```
   df <- data.frame(Value = c(50,10,30,40),
                    object = c("apples","tomatoes", "apples","pears" ))
```

and a share object with the percentages for the objects:

```
share <- data.frame(object = c("tomatoes","pears", "apples" ),
                   percentage = c(90,75,80))
```

My expected result is:

```
  Value   object
1    40   apples
2     9 tomatoes
3    24   apples
4    30    pears
```

With only one object I used this code, which works fine:

```
df[,1] <- df$Value * share$percentage /100
```

But how to perform this for the different objects in df/share? "aggregation"/"subset" or something like that?

**EDIT:** I have tried this so far, which I think it could be a way:

```
df[,1] <- aggregate(df$Value, by=df$object,FUN= function(x) {x$Value * share$percentage /100}   )
```

and

```
df[,1] <- apply(split(df, df$object) function(x) {x$Value * share$percentage / 100})
```

However, the function seems to be wrong (I'm nor really familar with functions:). 
Please note, that I don't want first to merge `df` with `share` as answered, as I need the original structure of df and order. So I'm looking for a short command. I really appreciate your ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a weighted average?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  inner_join(share) %>%
  group_by(object) %>%
  summarize(weighted_average = 
              sum(Value * percentage) / sum(percentage) )
```

Comment: this delivers a only an average for each product, but not for original df (see my expected result, df has 4 objects and you produce only the three levels in df)